# Are there any technical constraints to deploy from one or more LPARs to another?

Tags: zos

I'm creating a LPAR strategy to support:

1. A production support environment (copy of production)
2. Two separate function test environment for concurrent releases

Question: Is there any zOS technical limitation I need to be aware of to deploy from either test environment LPAR to either the Production or Production support LPAR in the above scheme?

Comment: What application(s), what data stores, what underlying hardware?  z/OS is designed to support such activity, but it's also a function of application design.  When you say "deploy" what do you mean?

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie As an example, by deploy I mean move the application and module version(s) that have just been certified in a test environment to the production LPAR, including the executables, libraries, supporting operational data, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, in general, z/OS will support that, easily.  Are there no system programmers there to assist with this work?  Or are you the system programmer?  I'm trying to understand the context for the question.  And, again, it may be very dependent on the application(s) you're using not having anything hard-coded in them that would have a problem running in a different environment, or running multiple instances in parallel (if, say, there's some sort of dependency on an external resource not controlled by z/OS).